# Is it possible to see which load cell is accounting for how much of the total weight?

Tags: load-cell

I'm a newb when it comes to electronics, learning it as a hobby and was wondering if it was possible to determine which load cell accounts for what % of weight when connected in wheatstone pattern. I'm using 4 bathroom scale load cells with 3 wires.

Apologies in advance if the question is uninformed or misguided!

Thank you all for your help :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.